# lighttpd server-status

Tags: configuration, lighttpd

I have enabled lighttpd mod_status as  /server-status. When I go to the URL, I get the status page. I am interested in monitoring connections -- most specifically KeepAlive connections to make sure KeepAlive is working correctly.

The problem is I only see the full connection info for the /server-status request itself. All other requests do not have the URI or hist columns filled in:

X.X.X.X     0/0 0/4673  handle-req  0   test.mydomain.com   /server-status (/server-status)

This makes it difficult to know which URL was last handled by a particular connection.  Is there something special that I need to do to show this information(URI) in /server-status?

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't possible before lighttpd 1.4.24 (see [bug entry](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1202)) - before then, the relevant fields in the connection structure were being reset after each request.